# SoapUI can send soap request, java xml cannot

Tags: java, soap

I have a project whereby I have to make a soap request to an endpoint. Using SOAPUI, the request goes quite well and I receive a response, but when I use Java, I receive the following error:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection post SEVERE: SAAJ0010: Unable to read response
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Anyone know why that is so? Here is the part where the call occurs:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
                SOAPMessage soapMsg = factory.createMessage(null, is);
                SOAPConnectionFactory connFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
                SOAPConnection conn = connFactory.createConnection();
                URL endpoint = new URL(Main.SOAP_END_POINT_TESTING);
                System.out.println(endpoint);

                SOAPMessage response = conn.call(soapMsg, endpoint); //right here is where the error is thrown
```

The connection is over plain HTTP

Comment: I was able to solve this by adding a connection timeout to the connection resource. I didn't understand how that could affect that specific request but it worked. Could someone close this please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
```

**You have to create body here and then save the changes.**

```
soapMessage.saveChanges();
```

Print the request message

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outRequest = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
soapMessage.writeTo(outRequest);
String request=outRequest.toString();

SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage,url);
```

Comment: So there will be two unused variables: envelope and request? I don't understand the code flow in your example

Comment: **envelope** will be used to add the data in body. In SOAP its like , every element is child to the parent and every SOAP request starts with Envelope(rest of the tags are child to it.). So we will add body to envelope. and Finally **request** will be used just to print the request which we are sending through SOAP.

Comment: can you provide sample request?

Comment: At the moment, no, its proprietary, so I can't divulge the full request. It's also limited to my intranet